# Foreign Key Constraint over two tables

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-11g-r2, constraint, subtypes

**I am trying to put the following entity-model into practice:**

1. We have a list of Payments, each Payment belongs to a certain store and is of a certain payment type *(e.g. 10€ maintenance cost in Store1, 20€ rent in Store2)*
2. A Payment Type is a categroy like *(rent, maintenance, legal fees, licenses)* and each category is assigned a certaing account_type *(e.g. budget_legal, budget_monthly, budget_extraordinary )* where multiple Payment types can have the same account_type
3. We have accounts: An account belongs to a certain store for a certain account type. So Store1 can have account-types *budget_legal, budget_monthly*, while Store2 has account types *budget_legal, budget_monthly and budget_extra*

#### Relationship Model:

[image: Diagram showing Relationship Model]

*Image Created with http://draw.io/*

Now I want a constraint that each payment must belong to an existing account. **I want to guarantee the following:**

1. When I change the account_type of a Payment_type, all payments of this type will then "belong" to the respective accounts.
2. If I delete an account I want to delete all payments in this account ( like delete cascade in a foreign key )
3. I can only insert/update Payments so that each payment refers to a valid store_id/account_type, which exists in the accounts table.

---

**Possible solutions which I tried but don't really work:**

I tried to add the **account_type** to payments, but then I have doubled the field - and when I change a Payment type I will have to change the referenced payments via trigger. - But in the best case I don't want triggers to enforce data integrity - and I don't want duplicate data storage.

I tried to create a foreign key constraint over multiple tables / a view which joins payment with payment_types. Unfortunately this seems to be impossible in Oracle DBMS

I tried to create a virtual column on Payments, which calculates the value from payment_types, but virtual columns can only reference columns in the same table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes first:

- Considering that `Accounts` has a `unique` constraint on `(account_type, account_store)`, a Payment seem to be associated with only one Account. That suggests that the FK from `Payments` should reference `Accounts` (and not `Stores`). This change will also solve issue #2.
- Adding `account_type` to `Payments` (and modifying accordingly the foreign key to `Payment_types`) seems like the most sensible approach and it will solve issue #3.
- The two changes together will solve issue #1.
- Oracle does not have `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option, so this issue (updating the account_type of a Payment_type to update the related Payments) needs to be addressed by either an update trigger or by a stored procedure (that will also check that related Accounts also exist (or are added) for all Stores that have Payments of the (updated) account_type.

The suggested design, assuming you also have an `Account_types` table (I renamed a few columns but that is up to you and your preferences / conventions):

```
Account_types
---------------
account_type_id  PK


Payment_types
---------------
account_type_id  PK, FK -> Account_types
payment_type_id  PK


Stores
--------
store_id         PK


Accounts
---------------
account_type_id  PK, FK1 -> Account_types
account_id       PK
store_id             FK2 -> Stores


Payments
---------------
payment_id       PK
amount
account_type_id      FK1, FK2 
payment_type_id      FK1 -> Payment_types
account_id           FK2 -> Accounts
```

Note how both foreign keys from `Payments` use composite keys.

[image]

Comment: This seems like the most sensible approach, since the trigger will only move payments to the correct account, but all constraints are checked by the db - so if the trigger fails for any reason, the constraint will fail and one can never commit inconsistent data.